# Django ownership foreign key to User or UserExtenstion

Tags: database, django, django-models, django-authentication, django-users

I'm quite new with Django, and so far I have a pretty basic setup where I attach an extra model to the default User model from (django.contrib.auth.models). In my accounts.models.py I have something in the line of:

```
class UserExtension(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    # more code
```

I also have another model which needs to be specified an owner. My question is: Which is the better (more django-ish, more readable, more efficient, more flexible) way to signify the owner:

```
class Owned(models.Model):
    # code
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # more code
```

or:

```
class Owned(models.Model)
    # code
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserExtension)
    # more code
```

I'll really appreciate if you mention pros and cons of those approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend the first option. The user model is the nontrivial model in the sense that an owned object should not be able to exist without a user, but could exist without a UserExtension.

Also consider that in Django 1.5 you are able to create custom user model, eliminating the need for the UserExtension class. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the note on Django 1.5, I somehow must've missed it, but I will most probably transfer to it despite being a RC. On a side note, in my case and Owned object, should be owned by a User with a UserExtension, and not for example a super user (which is purely administrative and doesn't have a UserExtension). Do you consider it overkill to secure that such a case doesn't occur both through the DB and programmatically?

Comment: For me, securing that programmatically would suffice in most cases. In general - also if you create your own user model - unless you have good reasons not to, I wouldn't make a hard divide between different types of users models (e.g. having seperate models for admins and ordinary users.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `UserProfile` for any per user add-on information. Check out this [blog](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/django-profile) to see how to do it. Then you can be assured that you are creating UserProfile object every time you create the User.

Now whether you FK on User or UserProfile depends logically on what you are doing within Owned. If Owned works with User's data/field, FK on User; if it works with UserProfile's data, FK on UserProfile.